# How to receive OTLP exported traces in Rust

Tags: node.js, rust, trace, open-telemetry

I want to monitor traces of my Node.js application, and I am using `@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-grpc` library for this purpose.

Now, I want to receive this traces in a Rust application. Unfortunately, Seems like there is no otlp receiver implementation in Rust as of now !

What is the best possible way (as of now) to collect these traces in my Rust application (preferably based on HTTP or GRPC) ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What do you mean by receive in rust? As in you are building tracing backend in rust? Or do you want to connect traces with context propagation?

Comment: I want to connect traces for context propagation.. the final backend is in golang.

Comment: I would prefer GRPC, because it is more effective (faster) protocol by design https://medium.com/@EmperorRXF/evaluating-performance-of-rest-vs-grpc-1b8bdf0b22da#:~:text=gRPC%20is%20roughly%207%20times,of%20HTTP%2F2%20by%20gRPC.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, you should rephrase your question. You don't want to receive traces in Rust. What you want is the context propagated from upstream application to your Rust process.

You need to use one of many possible context [propagators](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/main/specification/context/api-propagators.md#propagators-distribution) in your application. If you don't have already I would suggest using W3C context propagation https://www.w3.org/TR/trace-context/. All the SDKs have the implementation of these propagators.

Here is what you would do is to set the global propagator in both the Node and Rust applications and the propagation should be done automatically unless you have some rust application which is not yet supported by OTEL, in which case you need to do it manually.

In JS application

```js
const api = require("@opentelemetry/api");
const { W3CTraceContextPropagator } = require("@opentelemetry/core");

/* Set Global Propagator */
api.propagation.setGlobalPropagator(new W3CTraceContextPropagator());
```

In Rust application

```rust
use opentelemetry::global;
use opentelemetry::sdk::propagation::TraceContextPropagator;
...


global::set_text_map_propagator(TraceContextPropagator::new());
```

If for some reason your web server/client doesn't support the auto context propagation, given the OTEL rust is not very mature yet. You would have to inject/extract to and from header to achieve the propagation.

Manually Inject

```rust
global::get_text_map_propagator(|propagator| {
    propagator.inject_context(&cx, &mut your_headers
});
```

Manually Extract

```rust
let parent_cx = global::get_text_map_propagator(|propagator| {
    propagator.extract(&HeaderExtractor(req.headers()))
});
span = tracer.start_with_context("foo", &parent_cx);
```

Comment: How will the nodejs and rust application communicate ? Will there be a gRPC connection between them ?

Comment: @KevalBhogayata it uses GRPC metadata (ie. headers) in the request. If you log the GRPC request metadata, you'll notice a new field. For the W3C propagator, it probably looks like `"traceparent": "00-1b9b0efd7e2fc6e7c16a8362b1db27d5-322badfc41c805ec-01"`.